# How do I put this series in it's correct form?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Really frustrating, this seems so simple but I just don't know how to put it into the sum form.

This is the series : $1+x^3+x^5+x^7+\ldots$

Comment: It start with $1$ and not $x = x^1$?

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

For $x $ such that $|x|<1$,

$$S=1+x^3+x^5+x^7+.... $$
$$=1+x^3+x^2 (x^3+x^5+... $$
$$=1+x^3+x^2 (S-1) $$

thus
$$S=\frac {1-x^2+x^3}{1-x^2} $$

Comment: How does this answer the question? It was specifically asked for "sum form". That being said, the derivation of the rational form is good.

Answer (score 2):

We have that for $|x|<1$
$$1+x^3+x^5+x^7+\dots=1+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{2k+3}=1+x^3\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(x^2)^{k}=1+\frac{x^3}{1-x^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$1+x^3+x^5+x^7+\dots=1+\sum_{\text{n}=1}^\infty x^{2\text{n}+1}=1+\frac{x^3}{1-x^2}$$

When $\left|x\right|<1$

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to put all of it into a single, nice summation formula, for the simple reason that the first term has an invisible $x^0$, while all the other terms have odd exponents. My best bet would be something like
$$
1 + \sum_{i = 1}^\infty x^{2i+1}
$$
Now, if you meant $x + x^3 + x^5 + \cdots$ instead, then that would be a lot easier, since now the exponents are all odd numbers. That would make it
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^\infty x^{2i+1}
$$